# Can I upload an LPA file (Long Profile) to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, route, bathymetry, profile

I have a .lpa file that I'd like to upload to QGIS - can this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The file can be opened in Notepad, which can then be saved as a .csv and imported via mmqgis, so all fine here now!